# How to test which input has the focus when tab button is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm building a React autocomplete component and testing it using Jest and React-testing-library.

I have two inputs. When input1(with autocomplete functionality) is in focus, clicking the `Tab` button should either auto fill input1 with a text if input1 isn't empty, **or** move the focus to input2(which is the default behaviour of forms) if input1 is empty.

**form.jsx**

```
    const onKeyDown = (e) => {
        if(e.key === 'Tab' && e.target.value !== '') {
            setInput1Text('some-autocomplete-text');
            e.preventDefault(); //prevent focus from moving to the next input(input2)
        }
    };
```

**form.test.jsx**

```
    test('pressing Tab button should move focus to input2 as input1 is empty', () => {
        const input1 = container.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        const input2 = container.getElementsByTagName('input')[1];

        fireEvent.change(input1, { target: { value: '' } });
        fireEvent.keyDown(input1, { key: 'Tab' });

        expect(input2).toBe(document.activeElement) //failing, activeElement returns <Body>
        // OR
        expect(input2).toHaveFocus(); //failing as well.
    });
```

Currently, in my tests, `document.activeElement` keeps returning the `Body` element but I expect it to return either of the two inputs. Also `expect(input2).toHaveFocus()` fails.

How can I test that the focus has moved from input1 to input2?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I ended up using the @testing-library/user-event library.
I replaced `fireEvent` with `userEvent` for the `Tab` press.

My code now looks like this:

```
    import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

    test('pressing Tab button should move focus to input2 as input1 is empty', () => {
        const input1 = container.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        const input2 = container.getElementsByTagName('input')[1];

        input1.focus();
        fireEvent.change(input1, { target: { value: '' } });
        userEvent.tab(); //this line made it work

        expect(input2).toHaveFocus(); //passing now
    });
```

Reference: https://github.com/testing-library/user-event#tabshift-focustrap

Answer (score 0):

The function fireEvent.keyDown should work for you if you do the following:

- The component and the test, **both have to use KeyDown**, (using KeyPressed was one of my problems)
- Then the fireEvent can be called like this:

  ```
    fireEvent.keyDown(Element, {key: 'Tab', code: 'Tab', charCode: 9})
  ```

For more info on [key codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)